# Difference between Double.Vector and Vector<double>

Tags: c#, math.net

I've got problem with types while working with vectors in MathNet.
I'm using 
`using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double;`
so all Vectors and Matrices are type `Double.Vector` etc.
But for example if I want to get particular row from matrix ->

```
V.Row(V.RowCount-1);
```

it returns type `Vector<double>`, so this throws  "cant convert" error:

```
Vector v = myMatrix.Row(0);
```

Is there some `Vector<double>` to `Double.Vector` convertor or trick how its done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Double.Vector` inherits `Vector<double>`, so normal type casting should work, e.g. `Vector v = (Vector)myMatrix.Row(0);`.

However, since Math.NET Numerics v3 it is **recommended to use the generic types  only** (`Vector<double>`). The API is designed such that with the generic types you never have to do any such conversions or casts. There's even no need to open the `MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double` namespace, `MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra` is enough when using the `CreateVector` static class to create new vectors, and `AsArray` to get back to the raw array if needed.